# Not Able to Insert Taxonomy Term Using wp_insert_post()

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, wp-insert-post, terms

I have a Custom Post Type called `eyeglasses` and Custom Taxonomy called `models`. I also created two terms for taxonomy called `M156` and `M120`. Now I am trying to upload two post for test through `wp_insert_post`.

This is adding the `$title` to the `post_title` of `eyeglasses` but not adding or updating the term of the post.

```
function we_load_posts($title, $term)
{
    wp_insert_post(array(
        "post_type" => "eyeglasses",
        "post_title" => $title,
        "tax_input" => array(
                             "models" => array($term)
                           ),
        "post_status" => "publish"
    ));
}
we_load_posts("Montana", "M156");
we_load_posts("Havana", "M120");
```

can you please let me know what I am missing or doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Few points come to mind:

1. There is a typo in `"post_type" => "'eyeglasses"` (extra single quote). It should be: `"post_type" => "eyeglasses"`.
2. Try putting the `$term` instead of `array( $term )`:

   ```
   "tax_input" => array(
       "models" => $term
   )
   ```
3. Also, is it `models` or `model`? e.g.

   ```
   "tax_input" => array(
       "model" => $term
   )
   ```
4. `tax_input` requires `assign_terms` capability. So if the user you are running this CODE with, doesn't have that capability, it'll not work.

   In that case, the right way is:

   ```
   $post_id = wp_insert_post(array(
       "post_type" => "eyeglasses",
       "post_title" => $title,
       "post_status" => "publish"
   ));

   wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $term, 'model' );
   ```

Comment: Thanks for reply Nazaria, on `(1)` - Thanks I fixed the typeo, on `(2)` - I removed the `$term` out of array on `(3 )` - `models` is the name that I use to register the taxonomy. I fixed 1 and 2 as you said but still not able to add the terms with this code. On `(4)` I am not sure how to get the `$post_id` as I am running this code in a PHP file out of the theme directory by including `wp-load.php` to the file so not sure how this is gonna work! I just need this script for one time only upload

Comment: The number 4 actually worked! Thanks a lots

Comment: Thanks but can u please give me more hint on this ` you need to insert autho`

Comment: Check [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/), `wp_insert_post` argument array needs `post_author`. By default, WordPress takes the currently logged in user ID, however, depending on how you are running the external script, there may not be a logged in author. So, it's better if you provide an author id, like: `"post_author" => 1`

Comment: So if you don't provide an author ID and no author is logged in, WP will insert `0` as author.